# Different behavior between IE6 and Firefox for HTML Tables?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm doing the first bit of web-page development I've done in years, in VS2008, using VB.net. I have a fairly simple layout, which is using several nested tables. IE6 displays the layout just fine, but Firefox for some reason shows the whole thing in a small panel at the top of the page, with a scrollbar. Can anyone suggest something basic I am likely missing?

Comment: Sounds like you may be missing a closing tag or not enough <tr>'s. Do you have any example HTML as helping blind isn't easy.

Comment: Just use div's - they are better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference in a way that IE6 renders HTML and especially tables. If you want to support it you should write explicitly all the position related styles like width, padding etc, just create a css file for table style.

The good news are that IE7 and 8 are mush closer to the standard.